# Difficult to phrase blender problem with a rig using the tangent function

Tags: rigging, drivers, mathematics

What I want to happen, when I move the target bone, is for the Child bone to move only on the X and Y axis, NOT THE Z.

[image: 3 bones, a target bone, a bone constrained with a damped track, and a bone parented to the constrained bone.]

I figured I would use the rotational values of the constrained bone as drivers for the child bone, to correct the movement using the Z axis, I also figured it would use the "tan" function from the driver editor. Unfortunately, my knowledge ends there.

[image: Motion path, showing the incorrect trajectory of the child bone.]

I animated the target bone, so I could see the motion path of the child bone, and this is where I ended up. I have no idea where to go from here, but basically, I want this line to be straight, for this axis, and the Y axis.

Here is the blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fh9SK0OHeR6Qq2rDzDpFR4UErDs6W3_Z/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you show us the animation per link how it should look like?

Comment: i assume you know that you can set just x/y value for the child of constraint?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the question. *"... is for the Child bone to move only on the X and Y axis, NOT THE Z."* - this is the bone's axes that you mean here, not the global axes? What should happen when the *Target_Bones* goes back again (in a circle)? So [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx4iR.jpg or so
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCUS5.jpg?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work, without any math thankfully. To elaborate, this was meant to be an eye rig, on a flat surface, so I wanted the pupil to stick to the surface.
[image]

I used a  "stretch to" constraint on the 2 long green bones to point toward the purple master bone, and added a driver for the "original length" property of the constraint, to add the position of the master bone so that the stretch bone would always point towards the master bone, but not stretch out further than intended, and stick to a flat plane.